# Extract the number in cell in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

The cell contains text that matches the following pattern: number, unit, item, description. How can I extract the number from the cell to the consecutive cell

Comment: The question doesn't show any research effort. Please checkout [ask].

Answer (score 1):

To extract the start of the string up until the first comma:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"^(.+?),")`

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not as neat as @AdamL's solution but alternatives:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(split(A1,","),1,1) 

=value(left(A1,find(",",A1)-1))
```